# Implementing a Java interface featuring recursive type and bounds from Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, types

I have a problem that can be summarised by the following Java classes:

```
public class Foo<T extends Foo> {}

public class Bar<T extends Foo> {}

public interface AnInterface {
    public <T extends Foo, S extends Bar<T>> void doSomething(T thing, S other);
}
```

I am trying to implement `AnInterface` from Scala code and this is what my IDE advices:

```
class AnImplementation extends AnInterface {
  override def doSomething[T <: Foo[_], S <: Bar[T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit = ???
}
```

This doesn't compile as the compiler produces the following error:

```
type arguments [T] do not conform to class Bar's type parameter bounds [T <: foo.Foo[_ <: foo.Foo[_ <: foo.Foo[_ <: AnyRef]]]]
```

I tried to fix this in several ways; some failed experiments are:

```
// Failing with: method doSomething has incompatible type
override def doSomething[T <: Foo[_ <: Foo[_]], S <: Bar[T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit = ???

// Failing with: illegal cyclic reference involving type T
override def doSomething[T <: Foo[_ <: T], S <: Bar[T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit = ???

// Failing with: illegal cyclic reference involving type T
override def doSomething[T <: Foo[V] forSome { type V <: T }, S <: Bar[T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit = ???

// Failing with: method doSomething has incompatible type
override def doSomething[T <: Foo[V] forSome { type V <: Foo[_] }, S <: Bar[T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit = ???
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to get around this issue? Is it not possible to implement such a Java interface from Scala?

Comment: Im guessing it is something to do the fact that you are stating that the type in 'Bar' is of the generic type T,  you know what type T is going to be in your extending class, so you may as well hard code it in? (I havent coded in scala for ages so may have misread it!))

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the problem is that the type T is not defined at the class level (i.e. on `AnImplementation`) but only at the method level (i.e. on `doSomething`). The problem *is* related to the context bound of `Bar`, what I need is a way to satisfy that without making the function different in a way that wouldn't count as an implementation of the interface.

Comment: I don't have time to test it, but have you tried `T forSome {type T <: Foo[T]}`?

Comment: @Imm Thanks for the idea but if I just put that in place of `T <: Foo[_]` it doesn't compile; I am trying to use that same existential constraint in another way but I mostly get errors saying that the overriding method has an incompatible type.

Comment: @AldoStracquadanio `override def doSomething[T <: Foo[_], S <: Bar[_]](thing: T, other: S): Unit` seems to work, but I can't explain it yet.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Thanks, that solves the error I posted but it has two problems: the first is that I will lose the precise type that would be passed into `Bar`; the second is that the example I am reporting is a simplification of a more complex case where this trick doesn't work. If you want to see it in action try to implement the `execute` method of the `ElasticsearchClient` interface from Elastic search (http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.4.0/org/elasticsearch/client/ElasticsearchClient.html).

Comment: @AldoStracquadanio I've tried to implement that, but it's just too much. For the simpler example you've posted, this version seems to preserve the typesafety properties: `override def doSomething[T <: Foo[_], S <: Bar[_ <: T]](thing: T, other: S): Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not parameterizing the classes correctly. I believe this is what you're after:

```
public class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {}

public class Bar<T extends Foo<T>> {}

public interface AnInterface {
  <T extends Foo<T>, S extends Bar<T>> void doSomething(T thing, S other);
}
```

Then the implementation becomes:

```
class AnImplementation extends AnInterface {
  override def doSomething[T <: Foo[T], S <: Bar[T]](thing:T, other:S):Unit = ???
}
```